# libspotify API: how to retrieve cover art using libspotify API?

Tags: spotify

The post [Retrieve cover artwork using Spotify API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10123804/retrieve-cover-artwork-using-spotify-api) says there is no way to retrieve the cover artwork using Spotify's Web API, but I wonder if it's possible to retrieve the cover artwork **URI** using libspotify API.

I noticed there are few APIs:
**sp_album_cover** to get image ID representing the album's coverart, 
**sp_image_create** to create an image object from the ID, and 
**sp_image_data** to get image data from the image object.

Is the image ID returned by **sp_album_cover** the ID of image URI? e.g. ID is "3ad93423add99766e02d563605c6e76ed2b0e450" from "spotify:image:3ad93423add99766e02d563605c6e76ed2b0e450"?

What is the image data returned by **sp_image_data**? Is it the raw data of image itself (i.e. covert artwork image)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image data returned by `sp_image_data()` is in the format returned by `sp_image_format()` for that image - typically JPEG at this time.