# Get the cover of a track with the Spotify-API

Tags: spotify

is there a way to get the cover of a track by the spotify-API? I cant find there any paths to photo-files.

Best regards!

Comment: Which API? Spotify has several.

Comment: Cover art isn't available via the web API, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10123804/retrieve-cover-artwork-using-spotify-api