# is there any api to get album art from spotify?

Tags: php, spotify

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Retrieve cover artwork using Spotify API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10123804/retrieve-cover-artwork-using-spotify-api)

is there any api to get album art from spotify?

I m trying to retrieve details on the album via

```
$url_id = "some_spotify_album_id";
http://ws.spotify.com/lookup/1/?uri=spotify:album:$url_id";
```

I m getting the album name, artist name etc using the above api. But its not returning the album art.

Pls help, Thanks

Comment: A little searching goes a long way...