# Set artwork image for downloaded song

Tags: ios, objective-c, avassetwriter

I am downloading an mp3 file from an URL and I need to set the artwork image if the mp3 file does not include an artwork image (i.e. null).
The downloaded mp3 file is saving in document directory. Is it possible to set/change the artwork image of the mp3 file?

Comment: Is there anything in `AVURLAsset` to do that?

Comment: You can use the last fm or the Spotify api to get the artwork. See this SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10123804/retrieve-cover-artwork-using-spotify-api

Comment: I don't think Arunkumar is asking about where to get the artwork but rather how to set the artwork in the mp3 file metadata.

Comment: Shim is correctly said what I am exactly Expect

Comment: Is anyone have Idea in this?Please reply!