# Correct python syntax to search by artist in Spotify's Search API?

Tags: python, api, spotify

What is the correct python syntax for searching by artist with Spotify's API? Maybe I'm missing something obvious (been staring at this for way too long)

Per documentation, header 'authorization' & param 'q' and 'type' are required.
https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/search-item/

What I've tried:

```
artist_name = 'Linkin%20Park'
artist_info = requests.get('https://api.spotify.com/v1/search', header = {'access_token': access_token}, q = artist_name, type = 'artist')

ERROR: TypeError: requests() got an unexpected keyword argument 'q'
```

Then I thought, maybe the parameters has to be sent as a list?:

```
artist_info = requests.get('https://api.spotify.com/v1/search', header = {'access_token': access_token}, query = list(q = artist_name, type = 'artist'))
```

But:

```
ERROR: TypeError: list() takes at most 1 argument (2 given)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A list is a list, not a hybrid of a map and a list, such as in PHP. The [`list()` builtin](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-list) accepts either 0 or 1 positional argument, which should be an iterable. I'd highly recommend you go through the official [tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/).

You're probably using the [python-requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) library. In order to pass query parameters such as the `q` parameter, [you'd pass a `dict` of parameters as the `params` argument](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#passing-parameters-in-urls):

```
artist_info = requests.get(
    'https://api.spotify.com/v1/search',
    headers={ 'access_token': access_token },
    params={ 'q': artist_name, 'type': 'artist' })
```

Note that the headers argument [must be in its plural form, not "header"](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#custom-headers).

Finally, you might be interested in [spotipy](https://github.com/plamere/spotipy/blob/master/README.md), a simple client for the Spotify web API.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for :) Thanks. I also had to fix a type error because access_token and artist_name were variables instead of str. Does that mean I have to hard code values in the params, or is there a way to put a variable in there?

Comment: Nah, the variables most probably just contained something else than you expected them to. As usual, hard to say from just "type error" :P

Answer (score 4):

@Ilja's and @alfasin's answers provide good guidance but don't seem to work anymore as is.

You have to change to the `headers` params to `authorization` and add the string `Bearer`.

This works for me:

```
artist_info = requests.get('https://api.spotify.com/v1/search',
    headers={ 'authorization': "Bearer " + token}, 
    params={ 'q': artist_name, 'type': 'artist' })
```

Answer (score 2):

@Ilja's answer is good. Alternatively, you can embed the params in the URL (since you have only two of them and both relatively short), example:

```
artist_info = requests.get('https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?q={}&type={}'.format(artist_name, 'artist'), header = {'access_token': access_token})
```